# What is the best way to connect to GrapheneDB with a Typescript's library

Tags: typescript, heroku, neo4j, graphenedb

I only found [this typescript's library](https://github.com/tpennetta/neo4j-typescript) for Neo4j but there is no solution to connect with GrapheneDB (on Heroku).

Is anyone already found a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried out the library you mentioned yet, but there are many customers using the official [neo4j-javascript-driver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver). They've just merged a [PR](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/pull/251) with TypeScript declaration files for their public APIs. The next beta release will contain these changes but you can [already test them out](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/pull/251#issuecomment-310438757).

Regarding connecting to GrapheneDB from Heroku, you just need to use the [environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/graphenedb#environment-variables) that are added when you provision a new GrapheneDB addon. If you plan to use neo4j-javascript-driver you'll find a small snippet [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/graphenedb#using-with-node-js-and-neo4j-bolt-driver-for-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku site has a detailed [page on using GrapheneDB](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/graphenedb). It includes info on provisioning, how to use various drivers and languages, and a lot of other helpful information.

Comment: Probably a good reason not to answer overly-general questions, and instead flag them as "too broad", but thanks for trying to fix up this answer. I really still think you should at least mention something in here that is obviously relevant to the question, like a short summary of how to connect to GrapheneDB with a Typescript library.

Answer (score 0):

[Drivine](https://github.com/liberation-data/drivine) is a typescript library that allows connecting to a managed or self-hosted Neo4j database using the bolt protocol.

- Facilitates the use of well understood object-oriented and functional programming patterns.
- Supports implementation of code that adheres to a single responsibility principle (SRP). NestJS will be optional, but is recommended.* Takes care of infrastructure concerns, so that you can focus on making the most of your data.
- Removes boiler plate code, especially the tedious and error-prone kind.
- Supports streaming, without back-pressure. Large amounts of data can be managed in a timely and memory efficient manner.
- Light-weight use-case specific object graph mapping (OGM).